# Catch value in RowDataBound textbox in a gridview with autopostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a gridview that has the columns as below. These columns have textboxes with autopostback = true and need to get their value in RowDataBound of gridview. The problem is that when you type something in the textbox and take the focus off of it, occurs in the RowDataBound grid but the value entered is NOT captured (= /)

Help me to solve this problem, there is more to do. I can not use jquery or anything, only the TextChanged some textbox gridview to get the value.

Code:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Entrada">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmanha_g" AutoPostback="true" class="Mask" 
                         Width="40px" runat="server" 
                         Text='<%#Eval("ENTRADA") %>'>
            </asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Are you binding the grid view in `Page_Load`?

Comment: Yes, in page_load, I am giving a gridview.datasource = Datatable and then databind

Comment: Could you update the question with your RowDataBound evnet code?

Comment: Share your Rowdatabound field Code

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your GridView up to be editable and avail of the EditItemTemplate. Here's a working example:

[Editable Gridview with Textbox, CheckBox, Radio Button and DropDown List](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37207/Editable-Gridview-with-Textbox-CheckBox-Radio-Butt)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Bind grid here only on page load not every post back to the server
    }
}
```